# How to sum up subelements of a list of unknown length

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm simply looking for the `{}+{}` function for sublist elements of a list: (Parallel sums of elements)

```
c = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {8, 7, 6, 5}};
Plus[c]
Mean[c]  
desired={9, 9, 9, 9}
```

Where `Mean` does directly what it's supposed to, unfortunately `Plus` doesn't. I tried `Take` and `Part` but they both do not seem to work here . Additionally, my `c` consists of a varying number of elements. I tried to work with `Length[c]` and `Range` .. (`{}+{}` is no solution as list element number varies) thank you for help!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use either

```
Plus@@c
```

or

```
Total[c]
```

Comment: For completeness: if one treats the list of lists as a matrix, `Total[c]` and `Total[c, {1}]` sums columns, `Total[c, {2}]` sums rows, and `Total[c, 2]` sums all elements.

Comment: @J.M. Good points. For once, I did not try to be complete :)

Comment: Leonid, are you ill? :o)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Looks like that :)

Answer (score 10):

Before version 5, I used `Tr` a lot for summing vectors as `Total` wasn't available:

```
c = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {8, 7, 6, 5}};
Tr /@ Transpose[c]

(*
==> {9, 9, 9, 9}
*)
```

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
Apply[Plus, {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {8, 7, 6, 5}}]
(*
==> {9, 9, 9, 9}
*)
```

or its shortcut

```
Plus @@ {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {8, 7, 6, 5}}
```

Another way is

```
MapThread[Plus, {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {8, 7, 6, 5}}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another method that I hope will be instructive.

```
Sum[i, {i, c}]
```

> {9, 9, 9, 9}

In `TraditionalForm`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]