# Add elements in a sublist

Tags: list-manipulation

I have created a subset of arrays:

```
b = Subsets[Range[10], {5}]
(* Out= {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 8},
         {1, 2, 3, 4, 9}, ..., {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}} *)
```

This command shows the combinations I wish to evaluate with. How can I add the elements of each subset in the list above to get an output like:

```
{{15}, {16}, {17}, {18}, {19},..., {40}}
```

Comment: See also: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1805/5

Answer (score 10):

Not sure I follow, but maybe `Total[b, {2}]`?

If the list of lists form is important: `Transpose@{Total[b, {2}]}`, or more simply as Artes just posted: `List /@ Total[b, {2}]`

---

`Subsets` returns an unpacked array, and in that case `Plus @@@ b` is faster.  However, by packing the array this method will be an order of magnitude faster than `Plus`:

```
Transpose@{Total[Developer`ToPackedArray@b, {2}]}
```

Comment: I didn't realize that `Plus` can *ever* be faster than `Total`

Answer (score 9):

Use `Apply`on the first level of the list `b` (`@@@` is a shorthand), i.e.

```
Plus @@@ b
```

Or exactly what you want, then map `List` over `Plus @@@ b`, i.e.

```
List /@ Plus @@@ b
```

Comment: Aiming for brevity, you could also use: `Tr /@ b`

Comment: Precisely `{#} & /@ Tr /@ b`.

Comment: `List` is as short as `{#}&` :-)