# How do I flatten a matrix of lists while maintaining the structure of the list?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a 2x2 matrix of lists. For example, the matrix I am working with looks like

```
matrix = {{{a,b,c}, {e,f,g}}, {{h,i,j}, {k,l,m}}}
```

I want to define a function such that when I pass this matrix to it, it gives me

```
{a+e+h+k,b+f+i+l,c+g+j+m}
```

Obviously a bruteforce way I could do this is to just take

```
matrix[[1, 1]] + matrix[[1, 2]] + matrix[[2, 1]] + matrix[[2, 2]]
```

But is there a more elegant approach to doing this using some built in functions in Mathematica? I tried looking around but I could not find one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Dimensions[matrix]` is `{2, 2, 3}` so you can use dot on the left side:

```
matrix = {{{a, b, c}, {e, f, g}}, {{h, i, j}, {k, l, m}}};

func = {1, 1}.({1, 1}.#) &;
func[matrix]
(* {a + e + h + k, b + f + i + l, c + g + j + m} *)
```

Or alternatively specify which levels to sum in `Total`

```
Total[matrix, {1, 2}]
(* {a + e + h + k, b + f + i + l, c + g + j + m} *)
```

Answer (score 14):

```
matrix ~ Total ~ 2
```

> ```
> {a + e + h + k, b + f + i + l, c + g + j + m}
> ```

And, for fun:

```
☺ = +## & @@ +## & @@ # &;

☺ @ matrix
```

> ```
> {a + e + h + k, b + f + i + l, c + g + j + m}
> ```

Comment: For those, like me, who are lost-in-space over this one, and had to look it up:


`~`  ➡️ `Infix[]` https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infix.html


`@@` ➡️ `Apply[]` https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html


The `☺` symbol, well, that's just delightful flexing 

Answer (score 10):

you can flatten then MapThread

```
{{{a,b,c}, {e,f,g}}, {{h,i,j}, {k,l,m}}} //
Flatten[#,1]& //
MapThread[Plus]
```

> (* {a + e + h + k, b + f + i + l, c + g + j + m} *)

Comment: `MapThread[Plus] @ MapThread[Plus, matrix, 2]` is another option.

Answer (score 6):

We grab the matrix from the OP

```
matrix = {{{a, b, c}, {e, f, g}}, {{h, i, j}, {k, l, m}}}
```

### **0. Using [`Total`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html) + [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) + [`` Developer`ToPackedArray ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5692/add-elements-in-a-sublist/5693#5693)**

The code is:

```
Total[Developer`ToPackedArray@matrix // Query[Total, All], {1}]
```

### **1. Using [`Flatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) + [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) + [`Plus`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus.html)**

The code is

```
Plus @@@ Transpose[Flatten[matrix, 1]]
```

### **2. Using [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) + [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) + [`Plus`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus.html)**

The code is

```
Plus @@@ Thread[Flatten[matrix, 1]]
```

### **3. Using [`Total`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html)**

The code is

```
Total@matrix[[All ;;]]~Total~1
```

### **4. Using [`Sum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html)**

The code is

```
Sum[matrix[[xx1, xx2]], {xx1, 1, (Dimensions@matrix)[[1]]}, {xx2, 
  1, (Dimensions@matrix)[[2]]}]
```

The above is an automated approach of the following

```
matrix[[1, 1]] + matrix[[1, 2]] + matrix[[2, 1]] + matrix[[2, 2]]
```

that was explicitly mentioned in the OP.

All of the above give

---

> [image: list1]

---

Answer (score 5):

```
func = Apply[Plus, Plus @@ #] &;
func[matrix]
```

> (* {a + e + h + k, b + f + i + l, c + g + j + m} *)

Or:

```
func = Map[Plus @@ # &, #, {0, 1}] &;
func[matrix]
```

> (* {a + e + h + k, b + f + i + l, c + g + j + m} *)

Comment: very nicely done!

Answer (score 3):

```
matrix = {{{a, b, c}, {e, f, g}}, {{h, i, j}, {k, l, m}}};
```

A variant of bmf's 2nd answer using `MapApply` (new in 13.1)

```
MapApply[Plus] @ Transpose @ Apply[Join] @ matrix
```

> {a + e + h + k, b + f + i + l, c + g + j + m}

Answer (score 3):

```
matrix = {{{a, b, c}, {e, f, g}}, {{h, i, j}, {k, l, m}}};
```

---

Using `ArrayRules` and `GatherBy`:

```
Total@*Values /@ GatherBy[Most@ArrayRules[matrix], #[[1, 3]] &]
```

> `{a + e + h + k, b + f + i + l, c + g + j + m}`

Answer (score 2):

```
Plus @@ ArrayFlatten[matrix, 1]

(* {a + e + h + k, b + f + i + l, c + g + j + m} *)
```